# import openlayers3 in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, intellij-idea, openlayers-3, amd

I am starting up an ember.js app aimed at drawing and displaying maps.

I am using ember.js **v1.11.0** and ol3 **v3.4.0**

I managed to install ol3 via bower and import it using Brocfile.js:

```
app.import('bower_components/ol3/build/ol.js');
app.import('bower_components/ol3/css/ol.css');
```

I can use it as well without problem in my views, etc. What I would like if possible is to get rid of the server errors:

```
views/map.js: line 6, col 22, 'ol' is not defined.
views/map.js: line 7, col 19, 'ol' is not defined.
views/map.js: line 10, col 21, 'ol' is not defined.
views/map.js: line 11, col 19, 'ol' is not defined.
views/map.js: line 14, col 19, 'ol' is not defined.
views/map.js: line 17, col 17, 'ol' is not defined.
```

And if possible get autocompletion in my Intellij IDEA (make it recognise the ol library)

If somebody could give me a hand, that owuld be much apreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `ol` to your .jshintrc file. in the predef array:

```
"predef": [
  "document",
  "window",
  "-Promise",
  "ol"
]
....
```

And for the intellij-idea you should be able to get your answer from the docs here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html